# How to eliminate all scenarios where there is no content in the string? For example : "" vs " " And checking if the given word is an isogram

Tags: java, string

```
public class isogram {
    public static boolean  isIsogram(String str) {
        // ...
      
      boolean flag = false;
      String st = str.toLowerCase();
      String checker = String.valueOf(st.charAt(0));
      
      // check if the string is empty and return false
      if (st == ""){
        return flag;
      }
      
      // for each char in the string, check if it lies in the a-z range 
      // and that it obeys the isogram conition (no repetitions)
      for(int i=1; i<st.length()-1 ; i++){
        
        boolean cond_check = !checker.contains(String.valueOf(st.charAt(i)));
        
        if (st.charAt(i) >= 'a' && st.charAt(i) <= 'z' && cond_check ){
          flag = true;
        }
        else{
          flag = false;
          break;
        }
        
        checker = checker + st.charAt(i);

      }
      
      return flag;
    } 
}
```

I'm trying to check if the given word is an isogram (no repetitions and numbers). Not able to figure what the issue is. And also while eliminating the empty string, I think I have to try to avoid " " (empty strings with spaces as well because they count as characters). How to do that?

Comment: You could use [trim](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_trim.asp) to remove whitespace and check the length of the string instead of the content.

Comment: [.isBlank()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) (Java 11 or later)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I guess trim() is the backbone for isBlank() too. Still not able to pass the testcases. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: You don't check whether the first character is a digit.